# Abstract Algebra, group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is given that order of exactly eight elements of group G is 3. We have to find the number of subgroups of order 3?

I just know it has to do something with cyclic groups
And I'm guessing the answer is 8.

Comment: Suppose you have two distinct subgroups of order 3. What's their intersection?

Comment: I think identity?

Comment: OK. So if there were exactly two subgroups, say $e, a, a^2$ and $e, b, b^2$, how many elements of order 3 would you have? How about if there were three subgroups?

Comment: Order of a is 3 and order of b is three in their  respective subgroups if there were three subgroups then each oc their order would be three too

Comment: What's the order of $a^2$? Since it divides 3, it must be 1 or 3. Which is it? So with this information, how many elements of order 3 do you have in the two subgroups? What about in the three subgroups?

Comment: Yes order of a^2 will also be three and for the three subgroups there will be total 6 elements of order 3

Comment: So for 8 elements to have order of three there must be 4 subgroups. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ subgroups of order $3$.
Remember that in  a group of order $3$ there are $2$ generators .

Comment: But the order of the elements is 3 not the order of the group?

Comment: Do you know the theorem that the order of an element $g$ in a group always divides the order of the group?

Comment: Yes and also the cyclic groups

Comment: Consider the intersection of two subgroups of order $3$

Answer (score 0):

Improving the @Vincenzo Zaccaro's answer consider two facts:

$1)$

In a cyclic group the number of generators of $G$ that has cardinality $n$ is $\phi(n)$ where $\phi (n) $ denotes the Eulero's function. In your case $n=3$ and $\phi(n)=2$

$2)$

The Intersection of two subgroups is a subgroup. In your case the intersection of two cyclic groups of order $3$ contains only the unity. Remember if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ then  $o(H) | o(G)$. Therefore there are $4$ subgroups of order $3$